# Ajax Submit issue - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, braintree

I am not convinced my solution to submit a braintree transaction via Rails UJS and Ajax is correct, the reason being is i am seeing two ajax calls as opposed to one when submitting.

For example when turning ajax off (so removing remote: true) submitting a form seems to wait for a nonce before submitting the payment (I believe braintree takes over the submit event)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token_here", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "payment_method_nonce"=>"nonce_here_populated"}
```

But when submitting with remote: true enabled the first call is

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token_here=", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>""}
```

So i read that i need to wait for that nonce using the `onPaymentMethodRecieved` callback function, append the nonce to the form and then submit

```
braintree.setup(gon.client_token, 'dropin', {
  container: 'dropin-container',
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function (paymentMethod) {
   $('#braintree-transaction-form').append("<input id='p_nonce' type='hidden' name='payment_method_nonce' value='" + paymentMethod.nonce + "'></input>");
   $("#braintree-transaction-form input[type='submit']").submit();
  }
});
```

This results in two calls being made

1)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token_here=", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>""}
```

2)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token_here", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "payment_method_nonce"=>"nonce_here_populated"}
```

Only problem being is i have this in my controller which  dont think is correct

```
def create
  nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
  render action: :new and return unless nonce # Is this the way to wait for the nonce
  @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
              amount: 2500,
              payment_method_nonce: nonce,
              customer: {
                first_name: params[:first_name],
                last_name: params[:last_name]
             }
            )
end
```

my concern i guess is the two calls being made and my controller code.

Has anyone got any experience with Ajax calls with Braintree and Rails

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You might be running into a problem with the default behavior of your submit button, which is [something you could try disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false). However, there's nothing here to think that is the issue. Most likely there is a problem elsewhere in your setup. I would really recommend contacting [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) with your full code samples to help them walk through your issue.